# Classification method used in CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, classification, multilabel-classification

In the code developed below by [Mike Smales](https://mikesmales.medium.com/sound-classification-using-deep-learning-8bc2aa1990b7), he uses a MFCC as the feature extraction.  Can you tell me what is the classification method used by his code listed below?

Here is his code for the CNN Model:

```
# Construct model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The loss the author used is `categorical_crossentropy`.

```
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

From the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy), it is being setup as a multi-class classification problem.